# How is $\det(I+aXY)=\det(I+aX^{\frac{1}{2}}YX^{\frac{1}{2}})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I prove that
$$\det(I+aXY)=\det(I+aYX)=\det(I+aX^{\frac{1}{2}}YX^{\frac{1}{2}})$$ for positive semi/definite matrices $X, Y$ in complex plane and real positive $a$?

Thanks a lot,

PS. NOT homework. Self studying matrix analysis- Horn.

Comment: If $X$ is positive definite, then $I + aXY = X^{\frac12}(X^{-\frac12} + aX^{\frac12}Y)$, and $I + aX^{\frac12}YX^{\frac12} = (X^{-\frac12} + aX^{\frac12}Y)X^{\frac12}$, so it follows from $\det (AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(BA)$. For positive semidefinite $X$, I'd think it follows from continuity and the positive definite case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $B=I+aX^{1/2}YX^{1/2}$, then
$$
(I+aXY)X^{1/2}=X^{1/2}B,\qquad X^{1/2}(I+aYX)=BX^{1/2},
$$
and 
$$
\det(X^{1/2}B)=\det(BX^{1/2}).
$$